# How to turn \phantom on/off for an entire document before compiling

Tags: compiling, phantom

I want to create a cloze with a lot of formulas and a lot of `phantom` blanks. But in the end, I need two versions, one with blanks and one without. Manually deleting all `phantom` is no solution. Is there a way to keep all phantom commands but disable the phantom function (for an entire document) when compiling? In other words, a way to turn phantom on/off for different compilations?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}                    

\begin{document}

    \begin{align*}
        L(\lambda, x_1, x_2) &= U (x_1, x_2) - \lambda ( \phantom{p_1 x_1 + p_2 x_2 - m} ) \\
        \frac{\partial L}{\partial x_1} &= \frac{ \partial u}{\partial x_1} - \lambda p_1 \stackrel{!}{=} 0 \Rightarrow \phantom { \lambda = \frac{ 1}{p_1} \frac{ \partial u}{\partial x_1} } \tag{I} \\
        \frac{\partial L}{\partial x_2} &= \frac{ \partial u}{\partial x_2} - \lambda p_2 \stackrel{!}{=} 0 \Rightarrow \lambda = \frac{ 1}{p_2} \frac{ \partial u}{\partial x_2} \tag{II} \\
        \frac{\partial L }{\partial \lambda} &= - p_1 x_1 - p_2 x_2 + m \stackrel{!}{=} 0 \tag{III} \\
        \frac{ 1}{p_1} \frac{ \partial u}{\partial x_1} &= \frac{ 1}{p_2} \frac{ \partial u}{\partial x_2} \\
        \frac{ \frac{ \partial u}{\partial x_1}}{\frac{ \partial u}{\partial x_2}} &= \phantom { \frac{ p_1}{p_2}}
    \end{align*}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please clarify how the two versions should look like? Do you want one version that looks like the screenshot and the other version that show the text that was previously hidden in the `\phantom` command? If  so, you could add `\renewcommand{\phantom}{}` to your preamble to obtain the second version.

Comment: I extended the graph. Yes, that was what I am looking for. Thank you very much. If you post your command, I will accept it as an answer :)

Comment: @leandriis That's quite dangerous: `\phantom` might be used by other packages (e.g. `amsthm` and `mathtools` use it). The safer version would be to define a new command which defaults to `\phantom` and can be redefind at needs.

Comment: @campa: Definitely a good objection. I somehow already suspected some drawbacks.